# Amazon Lex Session.Conversation Limits

Tags: limit, amazon-lex

This is a 2 part question:

1. Is there any limit on number of sessions/conversations a Lex Bot can handle at a time?
2. Is there any limit on number of session/conversations for Lex Bot, that can be in open state at any point of time?

Thanks in advance!